# How to make TextInputLayout and EditText hint gravity same with TogglerVisibility?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

Currently I am working with login form and here is the output.

[image]

This is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleContentDescription="description"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/password_edit_text_height"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_border_statup_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But I want email and password hint gravity exact center. Without toggle it is showing center but with toggle it is not showing center. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can use drawable in TextInputEditText in that case you do not need the toggle you can use TextInputEditText drawable and drawable click event.

Comment: Use android:drawableEnd property in TextInputEditText and remove the passwordToggle Property from TextInputLayout

Comment: @AndyDeveloper then how do I switch password visibility? I want to use design support library without custom implementation. Is there anyway?

Comment: switch password visibility handle by drawable click event which you set using android:drawableEnd this property in TextInputEditText. But without custom you can not set this thing AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Just add transparent drawable to the left side of `EditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password_space"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password_space"
                    android:gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

For transparent drawable you can use whatever you want with `android:width="48dp"`.

Create drawable resource file in `drawable` directory with name `ic_password_space`.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="1dp"
        android:viewportWidth="1.0"
        android:viewportHeight="1.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M"
        android:fillColor="#0000"/>
</vector>
```